# How confirm issue fix is correct or not and resolve it in Angular + Sonarqube issues?

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

Could someone tell me the way to make sure whether the fix given for the issue mentioned SonarQube correct or not?

this is my first time I'm using sonarqube with Angular7+. Currently I'm seeing issue highlighted like below in SQ

**Remove this useless assignment to local variable "randowmVar".**

```
event(evt: any, level: any) {
let randowmVar = level;
if (evt.keyCode === ) {
      randowmVar = level - 1;
    } else {      
      randowmVar = level + 1;
    }
}
```

how to fix and check after giving fix this whether its correct or not?

I came across possible solution in SO, but couldn't understand that.

Kindly help me to understand how to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: what is `i` here??

Comment: @ShlokNangia sorry my mistake.. now updated

Answer (score 0):

Use Ternary operator instead

```
event(evt: any, level: any) {
   const randowmVar = (evt.keyCode === ) ? level-1 : level+1;
}
```

The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (`?`), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (`:`), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the `if` statement.

Comment: @Shiok Nangia .. really confusing with your solution when compare with my actual code

how to hanle nested if statement here. here is my actual snippet `event(evt: any, level: any) {
    let randowmVar = level;
    if (evt.keyCode === 8 && evt.which === 8) {
        randowmVar = level - 1;
      } else {
        const lvl = level.value;
        if (!lvl) {
          return false;
        }
        randowmVar = level + 1;
      }
    }`

Comment: then this might resolve your sonar issue `event(evt: any, level: any) {
    let randowmVar;
    if (evt.keyCode === 8 && evt.which === 8) {
      randowmVar = level - 1;
    } else {
      const lvl = level.value;
      if (!lvl) {
        randowmVar = level - 1;
        return false;
      }
      randowmVar = level + 1;
    }
  }`